# How to know which topic name in Firebase Notification in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am working on an application in which I have integrated Firebase to handle the notification. I just want to know how I can get the topic name which is sent from backend team to me. There are three topics in that and according to topics, I have to show the message in a different layout. I am getting title and body like this:

```
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        //handle the data message here
    try {
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Log.e("TITLE AND BODY", title + "\n" + body);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: In notification how to send topic in remote message.

Comment: {
  "message":{
    "topic" : "foo-bar",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message",
      }
   }
}

Comment: Yes I know this @RatilalChopda actually see to get body and title We write     String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(); but to get topic there is no such method like remoteMessage.getTopic()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `onMessageReceived()`, just use [`RemoteMessage.getFrom()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getFrom()):

> Get the sender of this message.
>
> This will be the sender ID or the topic for topic messages.

It should return the value of the topic name if the message received was from a topic.